# I keep getting "pygame.sprite.Sprite.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int" error

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a platforming game and I keep getting this error when I tried to add particles for when the character jumps, and I can't figure it out. Everytime I try and jump with the character the error pops up. I will need some help in order to fix this.

**Code for the Level**

```
import pygame

# Importing the necessary files
from tiles import Tile
from settings import tile_size, screen_width
from player import Player
from particles import ParticleEffect

class Level:
    def __init__(self, level_data, surface):
        # Level setup
        self.display_surface = surface
        self.setup_level(level_data)
        self.world_shift = 0
        self.current_x = 0

        # Particles
        self.dust_sprite = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()

    def setup_level(self, layout):
        self.tiles = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        for row_index, row in enumerate(layout):
            for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
                x = column_index * tile_size
                y = row_index * tile_size
                if cell == "X":
                    tile = Tile((x, y), tile_size)
                    self.tiles.add(tile)
                if cell == "P":
                    player_sprite = Player((x, y), self.display_surface, self.jump_particles)
                    self.player.add(player_sprite)

    def jump_particles(self, pos):
        jump_particle_sprite = ParticleEffect(pos, 'Jump')
        self.dust_sprite.add(jump_particle_sprite)

    def scroll_x(self):
        player = self.player.sprite
        player_x = player.rect.centerx
        direction_x = player.direction.x

        if player_x < screen_width / 4 and direction_x < 0:
            self.world_shift = 8
            player.speed = 0
        elif player_x > screen_width - (screen_width / 4) and direction_x > 0:
            self.world_shift = -8
            player.speed = 0
        else:
            self.world_shift = 0
            player.speed = 8

    # Checks for horizontal collisions with the tiles
    def horizontal_collision(self):
        player = self.player.sprite
        player.rect.x += player.direction.x * player.speed

        for sprite in self.tiles.sprites():
            if sprite.rect.colliderect((player.rect)):
                if player.direction.x < 0:
                    player.rect.left = sprite.rect.right
                    player.on_left = True
                    self.current_x = player.rect.left
                elif player.direction.x > 0:
                    player.rect.right = sprite.rect.left
                    player.on_right = True
                    self.current_x = player.rect.right

        if player.on_left == True and (player.rect.left < self.current_x or player.direction.x >= 0):
            player.on_left = False
        if player.on_right == True and (player.rect.left > self.current_x or player.direction.x <= 0):
            player.on_right = False

    def vertical_collision(self):
        player = self.player.sprite
        player.apply_gravity()

        for sprite in self.tiles.sprites():
            if sprite.rect.colliderect((player.rect)):
                if player.direction.y > 0:
                    player.rect.bottom = sprite.rect.top
                    player.direction.y = 0
                    player.on_ground = True
                elif player.direction.y < 0:
                    player.rect.top = sprite.rect.bottom
                    player.direction.y = 0
                    player.on_ceiling = True

            if player.on_ground == True and player.direction.y < 0 or player.direction.y > 1:
                player.on_ground = False
            if player.on_ceiling == True and player.direction.y > 0:
                player.on_ceiling = False

    def run(self):
        # Tiles for the level
        self.tiles.update(self.world_shift)
        self.tiles.draw(self.display_surface)
        self.scroll_x()

        # Dust Particles
        self.dust_sprite.update(self.world_shift)
        self.dust_sprite.draw(self.display_surface)

        # Player for the level
        self.player.update()
        self.horizontal_collision()
        self.vertical_collision()
        self.player.draw(self.display_surface)
```

**Code for the Class ParticleEffect**

```
import pygame
from support import import_folder

class ParticleEffect(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init__(self, pos, type):
        super().__init__()
        self.frame_index = 0
        self.animation_speed = 0.5
        if type == 'Jump':
            self.frames = import_folder('Hero/Dust Particles/Jump')
        if type == 'Land':
            self.frames = import_folder('Hero/Dust Particles/Land')
            self.image = self.frames[self.frame_index]
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)

    def animate(self):
        self.frame_index += self.animation_speed
        if self.frame_index >= len(self.frames):
            self.kill()
        else:
            self.image = self.frames[int(self.frame_index)]

    def update(self, x_shift):
        self.animate()
        self.rect.x += x_shift
```

import_folder is just a class used for loading images.

The full error is

```
  File "C:\School\KS5\Computer Science\Project\Coding\pythonProject\player.py", line 109, in get_input
    self.jump_particles(self.rect.midbottom)
  File "C:\School\KS5\Computer Science\Project\Coding\pythonProject\level.py", line 35, in jump_particles
    jump_particle_sprite = ParticleEffect(pos, 'Jump')
  File "C:\School\KS5\Computer Science\Project\Coding\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.add(*groups)
  File "C:\School\KS5\Computer Science\Project\Coding\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 133, in add
    self.add(*group)
  File "C:\School\KS5\Computer Science\Project\Coding\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 133, in add
    self.add(*group)
TypeError: pygame.sprite.Sprite.add() argument after * must be an iterable, not int
```

Comment: Same issue happens

Comment: It looks like at a place of your code you do not show (cf your traceback) you provide `~.jump_particles` with an integer instead of an iterator (of integers), hence the error you get. I.e. what does `self.rect.midbottom` look like ?

Comment: you have a typo in your ParticleEffect class, it should be `__init__`, not `_init__`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the `__init__()` method in your `ParticleEffect` class that is causing this issue.
The `def _init__(self, pos, type)` is missing a underscore `_` at the beginning.